# "svn log --stop-on-copy" failed to show changes made on a revision later than the version on which the branch created

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I found an interesting problem when trying to sync my branch with the trunk.

1. I created branch A off the trunk by "svn cp" command with r17964.

   ```
   svn log --stop-on-copy
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   r17964 | MYID | 2012-11-06 08:58:26 -0600 (Tue, 06 Nov 2012) | 2 lines
   JIRA-4749: added Sonar into Maven build.
   ```
2. I created branch B off the trunk by "svn cp" command with rev17965-17966.

   ```
   $ svn log --stop-on-copy
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   r17966 | MYID | 2012-11-06 13:38:42 -0600 (Tue, 06 Nov 2012) | 2 lines
   JIRA-4750: added condor soap module back to the trunk.
   ```
3. I merged the changes from branch B back to the trunk.

   ```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   r17967 | MYID | 2012-11-06 14:24:06 -0600 (Tue, 06 Nov 2012) | 2 lines
   JIRA-4750: merged back to the trunk.
   ```

Now I try to pull the changes made on branch B from the trunk into branch A.
However, "svn log --stop-on-copy" will not show the changes made in branch A which is really in the trunk.

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r17964 | MYID | 2012-11-06 08:58:26 -0600 (Tue, 06 Nov 2012) | 2 lines
JIRA-4749: added Sonar into Maven build.
```

What should I do to pull the change off? Thanks.

Comment: please, show **real commands** and **real output** - at least for latest log (with or without --stop) in branch HEAD you can't get 17964 without later 17988 revision **in any case**

Comment: Run the commands with the `-v` option, so we can see the actual see where it was branched.

Answer (score 2):

I don't follow your logic that branch "A" is part of trunk.  Once you create a branch it is its own independent entity.  It only knows where it was branched from.

After the promotion of changes from branch "B" branch "A" has no knowledge of those changes.

I think what you want is to [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) the changes from "trunk" into branch "A".  That will update the "A" branch with all of the latest changes incorporated into trunk.

If you are just looking for diffs use the svn [diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) command.